# Cannot access or open Facebook messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I was up to sending a very long message, about 90,000 characters, to a friend, I tried several times but I got an error sending the message.

Finally, I think part of my message was sent because I could see the characters in my message list under my friend's name.

When I clicked the name to see my whole message it wouldn't load the message. And *now* I can't access any of my messages and I get this message from Facebook:

> Sorry, messages are temporarily unavailable. Please try again in a few minutes.

How can I get access to my messages and conversations again?

Comment: I have tried IE 9, Firefox 13.0.1, and Google Chrome, non of them can load my message.

Comment: That happens sometimes because Facebook is having error in their part.I have experienced that a lot.You just have to wait for Facebook to fix it.

Comment: Well I have been waiting for about three days, now I can access the message list, but when I click on the name of that fiends of mine who I sent that long message to, I get the message of "messages are temporarily unavailable, please try again in a few minutes."
is it probable that I can't access my conversation anymore?

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems that what you experienced is no longer happening.

And, as stated in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70291/177684) the limit for a message in Facebook Messenger is 20,000 characters, which is true at the moment.

So, your message exceeds the maximum message length supported, and probably led to an unexpected behavior - the error and situation you described.

Nowadays, as from what I tested when trying to send a message that is too long: If the tab didn't got stuck by pasting the message, and you've been able to sent it, the following notice will appear in red under the sent message:

> ⚠️ These people aren't receiving messages right now.

Which means that the message wasn't actually sent (because of the exceeding length of it) and so it won't be delivered to the other person. If you'll refresh the page you'll see that the message wasn't sent and doesn't exist.